# ORACLE APEX Deleting rows with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am getting this error when i try to delete the records of the first table, where the ID of this table does not exist in the records of the second table?

```
delete APP_LOG 
from APP_LOG
left join APP_AUDIT on APP_LOG.ID = APP_AUDIT.LOG_ID
where APP_AUDIT.ID is null
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not supported by Oracle.
You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM APP_LOG al
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM APP_AUDIT aa
  WHERE al.ID = aa.LOG_ID
)
```